# Finding location of linker functions

Tags: c, linux, linker, libpcap

I have a situation where I recently added a bunch of `pcap` functionality to a shared library that I've written to do some packet sniffing/injecting stuff.

I installed the pcap stuff, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

wrote all the code, then tried to build it with my makefile

All compiled and linked no problem

But when I looked more closely I noticed I hadn't specified `-lpcap` as a library dependency

But the linker hasn't complained about any undefined references..

So the question is how is the linker finding those `pcap` functions that I've called in my library code?

I was aware that if you use socket.h functions they're contained within the standard C runtime lib so you don't need to explicitly specify a library dependency. Is it the same for `pcap`?

Is there a way of querying where the linker has found its functions, i.e. where it found the `pcap` functions in this instance? I'd like to understand whats going on, rather than just being glad it worked..

To clarify, can you find the specific library file (.so or .a) that the linker has used when linking to a function that my code references?

possibly a verbose option to see exactly what the linker is doing?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want to know the location of the so file or the location in memory? And why do you need this information for?

Comment: It will give `linker` error, check properly `Makefile` and `LD_FLAGS` somewhere `lpcap` dependencies are mentioned. I am thinking this way, may be wrong.

Comment: After reading again your post, I think I get what you mean. It might be that another shared library that you are linking against, already linked `pcap` and that's why you didn't need to explicitly add `-lpcap` in your makefile.

Comment: @pablo I've added a clarification to the OP

Comment: @achal i agree that i would expect to see undefined reference linker errors in the absence of specifying -lpcap. Bizarre that I'm not!